# $ \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} a_m \sin(m\pi x)\sin(l \pi x)dx = \frac{a_l}{2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, heat-equation

Why is this true?

$$\int_{0}^{1}u^0(x)\sin(l\pi x)dx = \int_{0}^{1}u(0,x)\sin(l\pi x)dx$$ $$ = \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} a_m \sin(m\pi x)sin(l\pi x)dx$$ $$ = \frac{a_l}{2}$$

where coefficients ${a_m}$ are determined by $u(0,x) = u^0(x)$ which are the initial conditions to $u_t(t,x) = u_{xx}(t,x)$

Answer (score 1):

It is true because of the trigonometric identity
$$
\sin(A)\sin(B)=\frac12\left[\cos\frac{A-B}2-\cos\frac{A+B}2\right]
$$

---

Series and integral can be switched in position if $\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m^2<\infty$, which is the case if $u^0\in L^2([0,1])$.